# Inbox unread messages keep appearing, even after reading

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've noticed today that there is a bug that means I keep getting unread message notifications, even for messages I've already read.

Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: My rep counter isn't clearing, nor is it accurately reporting my rep gains. My inbox doesn't seem to be updating properly with everything either...

Comment: I'm not getting the red notification, but if I open it I see four new messages.

Comment: This bug appears to be resolved today.

Comment: Yep, seems sorted for me too

Answer (score 3):

We had problems with a datacenter test that left our caching layer in a partially broken state.

All issues should now be resolved.

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268957/topbar-notifications-dont-go-away